# How to unmarshal JSON in to array of interface and use

Tags: json, go, interface, unmarshalling

I am having difficulty understanding how to correctly unmarshal some JSON data that goes in to an array of type inteface and then use it. I tried to make this example code as simple as possible to illustrate the problem I am having. The code can be found in the playground here: https://play.golang.org/p/U85J_lBJ7Zr

The output looks like:

> [map[ObjectType:chair ID:1234 Brand:Blue Inc.] map[ID:5678
>   Location:Kitchen ObjectType:table]] {  } false {  } false

Code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Chair struct {
    ObjectType string
    ID string
    Brand string
}

type Table struct {
    ObjectType string
    ID string
    Location string
}

type House struct {
    Name string
    Objects []interface{}
}



func main() {
    var h House
    data := returnJSONBlob()
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &h)
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(h.Objects)
    s1, ok := h.Objects[0].(Table)
    fmt.Println(s1, ok)
    s2, ok := h.Objects[0].(Chair)
    fmt.Println(s2, ok)

}

func returnJSONBlob() []byte {
    s := []byte(`
{
  "Name": "house1",
  "Objects": [
    {
      "ObjectType": "chair",
      "ID": "1234",
      "Brand": "Blue Inc."
    },
    {
      "ObjectType": "table",
      "ID": "5678",
      "Location": "Kitchen"
    }
  ]
}
    `)
    return s
}
```

Comment: The actual value behind the `interface{}` is a `map[string]interface{}`, not a `Table`, so you can't cast it, type assertion or not. Meanwhile, consider how you'd write realistic code if this _did_ work—for each `object` in `h.objects`, you'd have to type-assert the `object` to a `map[string]interface{}`, access its `ObjectType` field, type assert that to string, then use a switch statement to decide which type to unmarshal to, which is not going to be significantly prettier, or more type-safe, than just staying with the non-typed decoding and manually pulling out the strings.

Comment: Meanwhile, what you're really trying to do is unmarshaling JSON to sum types: a `House` contains an array of `Chair | Table` values. Which is something Go doesn't have any way to represent. In a different language, you'd simulate it with inheritance, with duck typing, or with tagged unions and type switching; in Go, you need to halfway-simulate all three. [This blog post](https://medium.com/@haya14busa/sum-union-variant-type-in-go-and-static-check-tool-of-switch-case-handling-3bfc61618b1e) seems to cover most of the bases.

Comment: Best advice: Do not do that. Write your own JSON unmarshaler which handles the conversion to the appropriate type.

Comment: @Volker can you give an example of how to do that?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example__customMarshalJSON Why is it so complicated to take a look at the official, complete, readable documentation which is full of examples. All you have to do is implement the other way around. You'll find tons of examples in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is practical, since this is a simplified version of your scenario. However, one way to do this is combine the two object types to a new one, `Object`, and then unmarshal them directly to `Object` instead of using `interface{}`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Object struct {
    ObjectType string
    ID         string
    Brand      string
    Location   string
}

type House struct {
    Name    string
    Objects []Object
}

func returnJSONBlob() []byte {
    s := []byte(`
{
  "Name": "house1",
  "Objects": [
    {
      "ObjectType": "chair",
      "ID": "1234",
      "Brand": "Blue Inc."
    },
    {
      "ObjectType": "table",
      "ID": "5678",
      "Location": "Kitchen"
    }
  ]
}
    `)
    return s
}

func main() {
    var h House
    data := returnJSONBlob()
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &h)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(h.Objects[0].Brand)
    fmt.Println(h.Objects[1].Location)

}
```

Prints:

> Blue Inc.
>
> Kitchen

Example here: https://play.golang.org/p/91F4UrQlSjJ

Comment: Not an answer. What if it must be interface array?