# parse complex json from http response

Tags: json, go

I'm doing a http.PostForm against an API and the result is a json.
The Json structure is like this:

```
{
    "sites": [
        {
            "site_id": 456,
            "status": "pending-dns-changes",
            "domain": "blabla",
            "account_id": 123,
            "acceleration_level": "advanced",
            "site_creation_date": 1515455285000,
            "ips": [
                "1.2.3.4"
            ],
            "dns": [
                {
                    "dns_record_name": "something.bla.com",
                    "set_type_to": "CNAME",
                    "set_data_to": [
                        "something.x.incapdns.net"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "original_dns": [
                {
                    "dns_record_name": "blabla2.com",
                    "set_type_to": "A",
                    "set_data_to": [
                        ""
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "dns_record_name": "blabla3.something.com",
                    "set_type_to": "A",
                    "set_data_to": [
                        "1.2.4.5"
                    ]
                },

            ],
            "warnings": [],
            "active": "bypass",
            "support_all_tls_versions": false,
            "use_wildcard_san_instead_of_full_domain_san": true,
            "add_naked_domain_san": true,
            "additionalErrors": [],
            "display_name": "something.blablabla2.com",
            "security": {
                "waf": {
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "action": "api.threats.action.alert",
                            "action_text": "Alert Only",
                            "id": "api.threats.sql_injection",
                            "name": "SQL Injection"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "api.threats.action.alert",
                            "action_text": "Alert Only",
                            "id": "api.threats.cross_site_scripting",
                            "name": "Cross Site Scripting"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "api.threats.action.alert",
                            "action_text": "Alert Only",
                            "id": "api.threats.illegal_resource_access",
                            "name": "Illegal Resource Access"
                        },
                        {
                            "block_bad_bots": true,
                            "challenge_suspected_bots": false,
                            "id": "api.threats.bot_access_control",
                            "name": "Bot Access Control"
                        },
                        {
                            "activation_mode": "api.threats.ddos.activation_mode.auto",
                            "activation_mode_text": "Auto",
                            "ddos_traffic_threshold": 1000,
                            "id": "api.threats.ddos",
                            "name": "DDoS"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "api.threats.action.quarantine_url",
                            "action_text": "Auto-Quarantine",
                            "exceptions": [
                                {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "urls": [
                                                {
                                                    "value": "/neverbogus.pvr",
                                                    "pattern": "EQUALS"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "api.rule_exception_type.url",
                                            "name": "URL"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": 1618746719
                                },
                                {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "urls": [
                                                {
                                                    "value": "/doubleneverbogus.pvr",
                                                    "pattern": "EQUALS"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": "/ddoubleneverbogus.pvr",
                                                    "pattern": "EQUALS"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "api.rule_exception_type.url",
                                            "name": "URL"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": 856301271
                                },
                                {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "client_apps": [
                                                "537"
                                            ],
                                            "id": "api.rule_exception_type.client_app_id",
                                            "name": "Client app ID"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": 58318563
                                },
                                {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "ips": [
                                                "192.168.66.66"
                                            ],
                                            "id": "api.rule_exception_type.client_ip",
                                            "name": "IP"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": 707083378
                                },
                                {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "geo": {
                                                "countries": [
                                                    "BF"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "id": "api.rule_exception_type.country",
                                            "name": "Country"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": 1432086237
                                },
                                {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "user_agents": [
                                                "gasdfafafdfasdfadsfadsffads"
                                            ],
                                            "id": "api.rule_exception_type.user_agent",
                                            "name": "User agent"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": 1876871261
                                },
                                {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "parameters": [
                                                "bogusparamnamehere234"
                                            ],
                                            "id": "api.rule_exception_type.http_parameter",
                                            "name": "Http parameter"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": 1338747790
                                }
                            ],
                            "id": "api.threats.backdoor",
                            "name": "Backdoor Protect"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "api.threats.action.alert",
                            "action_text": "Alert Only",
                            "id": "api.threats.remote_file_inclusion",
                            "name": "Remote File Inclusion"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "api.threats.action.disabled",
                            "action_text": "Ignore",
                            "id": "api.threats.customRule",
                            "name": "IncapRules"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "sealLocation": {
                "id": "api.seal_location.none",
                "name": "No seal "
            },
            "ssl": {
                "origin_server": {
                    "detected": true,
                    "detectionStatus": "ok"
                },
                "custom_certificate": {
                    "active": false
                },
                "generated_certificate": {
                    "ca": "GS",
                    "validation_method": "dns",
                    "validation_data": [
                        {
                            "dns_record_name": "blablablasomething2",
                            "set_type_to": "TXT",
                            "set_data_to": [
                                "somethingtexty"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "san": [
                        "*.blabla2.com"
                    ],
                    "validation_status": "done"
                }
            },
            "siteDualFactorSettings": {
                "enabled": false,
                "customAreas": [],
                "customAreasExceptions": [],
                "allowAllUsers": true,
                "shouldSuggestApplicatons": true,
                "allowedMedia": [
                    "ga",
                    "sms"
                ],
                "shouldSendLoginNotifications": true,
                "version": 0
            },
            "login_protect": {
                "enabled": false,
                "specific_users_list": [],
                "send_lp_notifications": true,
                "allow_all_users": true,
                "authentication_methods": [
                    "ga",
                    "sms"
                ],
                "urls": [],
                "url_patterns": []
            },
            "performance_configuration": {
                "advanced_caching_rules": {
                    "never_cache_resources": [],
                    "always_cache_resources": []
                },
                "acceleration_level": "advanced",
                "async_validation": true,
                "minify_javascript": true,
                "minify_css": true,
                "minify_static_html": true,
                "compress_jpeg": true,
                "compress_jepg": true,
                "progressive_image_rendering": false,
                "aggressive_compression": false,
                "compress_png": true,
                "on_the_fly_compression": true,
                "tcp_pre_pooling": true,
                "comply_no_cache": false,
                "comply_vary": false,
                "use_shortest_caching": false,
                "perfer_last_modified": false,
                "prefer_last_modified": false,
                "disable_client_side_caching": false,
                "cache300x": false,
                "cache_headers": []
            },
            "extended_ddos": 1000000,
            "log_level": "security",
            "incap_rules": [
                {
                    "id": 51589,
                    "name": "Wordpress",
                    "action": "api.rule_action_type.rule_action_alert",
                    "rule": "(URL contains \"/xmlrpc.php$\" | URL contains \"/wp-login.php$\") & (User-Agent == \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36\" | User-Agent == \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1\")",
                    "creation_date": 1518810206000
                },
                {
                    "id": 52179,
                    "name": "No Browser",
                    "action": "api.rule_action_type.rule_action_alert",
                    "rule": "(ClientType != Browser & ClientType != SpamBot & ClientType != DDoSBot & ClientType != SiteHelper) & (User-Agent != \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534+ (KHTML, like Gecko) BingPreview/1.0b\" & User-Agent != \"Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)\")",
                    "creation_date": 1519432068000
                }
            ],
            "res": 0,
            "res_message": "OK",
            "debug_info": {
                "id-info": "13019"
            }
        },
```

API Docs: https://docs.imperva.com/bundle/cloud-application-security/page/api/sites-api.htm#List

This seems to be very painful for me to understand in go as I'm just starting..
From what I've been reading I should just define an object of type struct with my expected format.
Any way I can tackle this a lot easier? I'm interested in extracted for each individual site a few items like site_id / ips / domain.

Unsure how I should tackle this. I've been trying to get my head around https://github.com/buger/jsonparser but I'm failing to actually understand how to use it.

So far what I've been doing is:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting this..")
    formData := url.Values{
        "api_id":    {keyid},
        "api_key":   {apikey},
        "page_size": {"100"},
        "page_num":  {"0"},
    }
    response, err := http.PostForm("https://my.imperva.com/api/prov/v1/sites/list", formData)
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println("Ooops..", err)
    }
    log.Println(response.Status)

    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var results map[string]interface{}
    fmt.Println(string(bodyBytes))
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(bodyBytes), &results)
    defer response.Body.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to extract a couple of fields, you don't really need to define an elaborate `struct` type to describe the whole structure. You can use the stdlib to  unmarshal the JSON into a `map[string]interface{}` and then use something like this function to look for interesting keys:

```
// findNested looks for a key named s in map m. If values in m map to other
// maps, findNested looks into them recursively. Returns true if found, and
// the value found.
func findNested(m map[string]interface{}, s string) (bool, interface{}) {
  // Try to find key s at this level
  for k, v := range m {
    if k == s {
      return true, v
    }
  }
  // Not found on this level, so try to find it nested
  for _, v := range m {
    nm, ok := v.(map[string]interface{})
    if ok {
      found, val := findNested(nm, s)
      if found {
        return found, val
      }
    }
  }
  // Not found recursively
  return false, nil
}
```

This code deals only with nested maps. You can adjust it slightly to see through slices, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a single, complex go struct that reflects the entire json object structure, and annotate all of the elements with the json object/element names.

You can define simple structs for each of the nested objects, and annotate these structs with the json object/element names; and then build the complex struct by composing these structs.

Either of these are a ton of effort. You do not need the entire struct, you only need a few elements.

You can either define only the parts of the struct that you need to extract, and annotate those, or you can use the map[string]interface approach you have used. Both approaches work well.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    // your http query/response here

    // Declare an empty interface
    var results map[string]interface{}

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(body))
    // Unmarshal or Decode the JSON to the interface.
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &results)
    defer response.Body.Close()

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(empJson), &result)

    //Reading each value by its key
    fmt.Println("site_id:", result["site_id"],
        "\ndomain:", result["domain"],
        "\nip:", result["ips"][0],
        // etc
    )
}
```

See also:
[How to unmarshal JSON in to array of interface and use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710160/how-to-unmarshal-json-in-to-array-of-interface-and-use)